# Email validation error appearing twice in obj.errors.full_messages (Rails 3.2, Devise, RSpec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, devise

I am writing simple model tests for my User model. One of them checks for the presence of the `:email` attribute:

```
  it "is invalid without an email" do 
    expect(user = User.new(email: nil)).to have(1).errors_on(:email)
  end
```

For some reason this test is failing because the errors hash is including "email can't be blank" twice:

```
Failures:

  1) User is invalid without an email
     Failure/Error: expect(user = User.new(email: nil)).to have(1).errors_on(:email)
       expected 1 errors on :email, got 2
```

When I create the User with `nil` email in the console and call `user.errors.full_messages` I get the following:

```
 @messages=
  {:email=>["can't be blank", "can't be blank"]
```

This is what my validation looks like in `user.rb`:

```
validates_presence_of :email
```

Oddly enough, if I remove the above code from `user.rb` the test now passes and I only get the error one time in the errors hash.

What is going on here? I should note that my User model was created through the Devise generator. Does Devise already include a validation for `:email`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Your assumption is correct. devise has its own validation for email not be blank.You can remove your's.